# How can I locate the Javascript for some effect when using Firefox to debug a page?

Tags: javascript, firefox

When I want to simulate a website and I know there is some effect done via Javascript, e.g. the mouse hovers over a menu category, the sub menu automatically drops down and changes the menu category's background color.

But how can I know in exactly which line in which Javascript file this effect is triggered? This leads to a follow-up question: when I debug a page using Firefox's built-in debug tools, are all JS files of this page downloaded to my local machine? Does this mean that when I'm sure about some Javascript effect taking place, I can find that code on my machine?

Comment: It exists on your local machine but there is no way to tell exactly which one is doing what but you may make a guess.

Comment: Just fyi, whenever you visit a page on the web, all assets (HTML, images, CSS, javascript, fonts, etc.) are automatically downloaded to your machine (else the browser wouldn't be able to display or do anything). And what you are trying to achieve will often not be possible, as javascript is often minified.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your browser downloads every Javascript file. That doesn't help to find the source of the effect you're interested in, however. You can just do that in your debugger.

To find the file that causes the effect you're interested in, make a copy of the page and comment out Javascripts until the effect disappears. For maximum efficiency, use binary search -- comment out half of the files to see if it's in those, if not comment out the other half, then comment out half of the remaining, etc. (Dependencies will make it a little more complicated, but you'll figure it out.)

To find the line, once you have it down to a file, put a breakpoint at the top and step through with the debugger until you see your effect occur.

Comment: thank you for your reply , i have find it, it's strange that the javascript code is contain in a CSS file, so I spend a little more time to find it.